Unaligned Widgets in a Layout (in the GroupBox)
I'm trying in vain to center align a button and a text, both placed in a layout.
Himself placed in a GroupBox.
I have this code :
// Initialization
QScrollArea *centralFrame   = new QScrollArea();
QWidget *centralWidget      = new QWidget;
QVBoxLayout *centerLayout   = new QVBoxLayout();
QGroupBox *infoGroup        = new QGroupBox();
QGridLayout *infoLayout     = new QGridLayout();
QGroupBox *buttonGroup      = new QGroupBox();
buttonGroup->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
QVBoxLayout *buttonLayout   = new QVBoxLayout();
buttonLayout->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
QPushButton *userButton     = new QPushButton();

centralWidget->setLayout(centerLayout);

// Set Styles
infoGroup->setStyleSheet("QGroupBox { background-color: #cfe2cf; border: 1px solid #1a651a; border-radius: 4px;} QLabel { color: #1d301d; }");
buttonGroup->setStyleSheet("QGroupBox { background-color: white; border: 1px solid #1a651a; border-radius: 4px;} QLabel { color: black; }");

// Defintion Bouton
userButton->setText("Select this User");
userButton->setStyleSheet("background-color: #dfdfdf; border: 1px solid #333333");
userButton->setMaximumWidth(110);

// Add Widgets at Button Group
buttonLayout->addWidget(userButton,Qt::AlignCenter);
buttonLayout->addWidget(new QLabel("Instructions for using the Button"),Qt::AlignCenter);
buttonGroup->setLayout(buttonLayout);

// Add Widgets at Infos Group
infoLayout->addWidget(new QLabel("Last Name : <b>QUIDAM</b>"));
infoLayout->addWidget(new QLabel("First Name : <b>Jean-Paul</b>"));
infoLayout->addWidget(buttonGroup);

// Set Layout and Frames
infoGroup->setLayout(infoLayout);
centerLayout->addWidget(infoGroup);
centralFrame->setWidget(centralWidget);
setCentralWidget(centralFrame);

And the rendering gives this :

What am I doing wrong...?

The second argument of QBoxLayout::addWidget() is the stretch, not the alignment. Change to addWidget(userButton, 0, Qt::AlignCenter). Then: setting the alignment of the layout sets its alignment within its container (the widget or a parent layout), not that of its widgets. Finally, if you tried to use buttonGroup->setAlignment for that, then it's inappropriate, since that sets the alignment of the title, as the documentation explains.

@musicamante Thanks for your answer and your explanations about setAlignment of QGroupBox. But if I use correctly addWidget function using strech parameter, the width of my button change. As you can see in this photo picture

With the help of @musicamante I found a solution and I answer my own question
I replace this code
// Defintion Bouton
userButton->setText("Select this User");
userButton->setStyleSheet("background-color: #dfdfdf; border: 1px solid #333333");
userButton->setMaximumWidth(110);

by this code (to define the button width with CSS)
// Defintion Bouton
userButton->setText("Select this User");
userButton->setStyleSheet("background-color: #dfdfdf; border: 1px solid #333333; width: 110px");

I replace this code
// Add Widgets at Button Group
buttonLayout->addWidget(userButton,Qt::AlignCenter);

by this code (using correctly addWidget and strech parameter)
// Add Widgets at Button Group
buttonLayout->addWidget(userButton,0,Qt::AlignCenter);

And like @musicamante says, I delete this code
buttonGroup->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);

Hope this question and solution can help

QPushButton automatically expands its width to what the parent layout allows. Calling setMaximumWidth() (as the name suggests) only tells it the maximum width it can have, but that doesn't prevent it to have a smaller width. Read the addWidget() docs I linked above: the widget fills the entire cell IF the alignment is 0. Using arbitrary sizes is also discouraged, unless you have proper knowledge about style geometry hints (including font sizes, font scaling and DPI settings). If you just want the button to occupy the full available width, then simply do addWidget(userButton).
